# Trying to compile kernel module in Windows Subsystem for Linux error

Tags: makefile, kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run make after creating this makefile from this website
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html

When I run make in WSL I get `make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft/build M=/mnt/c/Users/tdwil/OneDrive/code/Documents/cfiles/systems/linuxkernel modules`

> make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
>
> Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2

Is this because make isn't possible in WSL? Or am I typing some directory wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not have Linux header on WSL. 
Another problem with Windows that Linux kernel have several file names which are differ in case.

It is better to compile kernel or kenel modules on Linux machines or VM.